# How to hide an open app icon from the dock in Catalina using bash or applescript?

Tags: bash, macos, applescript, macos-catalina, dock

is there a way to disable showing an app icon on the dock when open?

I'm using a bash script with this bit which hides the app window, but not the icon:
`open /Applications/Appname.app --hide`

I've been trying by manipulating the 'show-recents' key value in **com.apple.dock**, but even I could set the option on or off effectively, it has no effect on the app icon, it's still visible in the dock next to the bin while open.

I'm also trying the LSUIElement of the app's Info.plist, but I'm being unsuccessful. If I touch that file then the app crashes when opening.

Scenario: The app is Symantec Endpoint Protection. We recently got rid of it by running a script on a policy from our MDM. In order to make it fully silent, we decided to leave its system extension untouched (Catalina, SIP, etc). Now I've created another policy and script which, in order to terminate the system extension, it installs Symantec again and then via applescript it moves the app to the bin. This way the user gets a pop up that needs to authorise the termination of the system extension (not silent). This is ok.
The scrip opens SEP in the background to re engage the system extension and then kills the app. Here is where I want SEP not to be shown on the dock, during those seconds where it opens.

I'm working in another approach now: Hide dock > Disable show recent apps > open app silently and kill it > Enable show recent apps > Show Dock.

This works perfectly. However it will mess the dock properties for people that already have it set to autohide or that already have no show recent apps.

**The question here is, how can I detect the current status of those Dock preferences, before changing them?**

Comment: I'm a little confused abut the setup here. You mention a bash scripted an app window, but you don't say what the app, how it relates to the bash script, or what kind of app it is. Is this an app you developed, and AppleScript app, something downloaded form the internet? and it is something that needs to use the menu bar, or is it a background app?

Comment: Federico Joly, The information you put in comments really should be incorporated into the question not placed in a string of comments, as comment are ofter not read.  Case in point, your first comment with "LSUIElement", a now deleted answer covered that and had that individual read the first comment they may not have posted an answer for "LSUIElement" which is of no use to you since you've already tried it and it cause issues in your use case.  Please incorporate your comments into the question and then delete the comments.

Comment: Wow, this is an *entirely* different problem. basically you're asking us to find a way to make your hack invisible, not asking whether there's a way to achieve your goal (removing a system extension) without using your hack. The question you are asking is difficult info impossible: there's no way I see of hiding a dock icon without changing LSUIElement (which will raise security complaints). The other problem seems more approachable.